# MySQL Optimization for data tables and Query optimization

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, query-optimization

So a LOT of details here, my main objective is to do this as fast as possible.

- I am calling an API which returns a large json encoded string.
- I am storing the quoted encoded string into MySQL (InnoDB) with 3 fields: (tid (key), json, tags) in a table called `store`.
- I will, at up to 3+ months later, pull information from this database by using:

  ```
  WHERE tags LIKE "%something%" AND "%somethingelse%"
  ```
- Tags are + delimited. (Which makes them too long to be efficiently keyed.) 
  Example:

  ```
  'anime+pikachu+shingeki no kyojin+pokemon+eren+attack on titan+'
  ```
- I do not wish to repeat API calls at ANYTIME. If you are going to include an API call use:

  ```
  API(tag, time);
  ```

All of the JSON data is needed.

This table is an active archive.

One Idea I had was to put the tags into their own 2 column table (pid, tag (key)). pid points to tid in the `store` table.

**Questions**

1. Are there any MySQL configurations I can change to make this faster?
2. Are there any table structure changes I can do to make this faster?
3. Is there anything else I can do to make this faster?

QUOTED JSON Example (Messy, to see another clean example see TUMBLR APIv2):
`'{\"blog_name\":\"roxannemariegonzalez\",\"id\":62108559921,\"post_url\":\"http:\\/\\/roxannemariegonzalez.tumblr.com\\/post\\/62108559921\",\"slug\":\"\",\"type\":\"photo\",\"date\":\"2013-09-24 00:36:56 GMT\",\"timestamp\":1379983016,\"state\":\"published\",\"format\":\"html\",\"reblog_key\":\"uLdTaScb\",\"tags\":[\"anime\",\"pikachu\",\"shingeki no kyojin\",\"pokemon\",\"eren\",\"attack on titan\"],\"short_url\":\"http:\\/\\/tmblr.co\\/ZxlLExvrzMen\",\"highlighted\":[],\"bookmarklet\":true,\"note_count\":19,\"source_url\":\"http:\\/\\/weheartit.com\\/entry\\/78231354\\/via\\/roxannegonzalez?page=2\",\"source_title\":\"weheartit.com\",\"caption\":\"\",\"link_url\":\"http:\\/\\/weheartit.com\\/entry\\/78231354\\/via\\/roxannegonzalez\",\"image_permalink\":\"http:\\/\\/roxannemariegonzalez.tumblr.com\\/image\\/62108559921\",\"photos\":[{\"caption\":\"\",\"alt_sizes\":[{\"width\":500,\"height\":444,\"url\":\"http:\\/\\/31.media.tumblr.com\\/c8a87bee925b0b0674773af63e43f954\\/tumblr_mtltpkLvuo1qmfyxko1_500.png\"},{\"width\":400,\"height\":355,\"url\":\"http:\\/\\/25.media.tumblr.com\\/c8a87bee925b0b0674773af63e43f954\\/tumblr_mtltpkLvuo1qmfyxko1_400.png\"},{\"width\":250,\"height\":222,\"url\":\"http:\\/\\/31.media.tumblr.com\\/c8a87bee925b0b0674773af63e43f954\\/tumblr_mtltpkLvuo1qmfyxko1_250.png\"},{\"width\":100,\"height\":89,\"url\":\"http:\\/\\/25.media.tumblr.com\\/c8a87bee925b0b0674773af63e43f954\\/tumblr_mtltpkLvuo1qmfyxko1_100.png\"},{\"width\":75,\"height\":75,\"url\":\"http:\\/\\/25.media.tumblr.com\\/c8a87bee925b0b0674773af63e43f954\\/tumblr_mtltpkLvuo1qmfyxko1_75sq.png\"}],\"original_size\":{\"width\":500,\"height\":444,\"url\":\"http:\\/\\/31.media.tumblr.com\\/c8a87bee925b0b0674773af63e43f954\\/tumblr_mtltpkLvuo1qmfyxko1_500.png\"}}]}'`

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Mysql MATCH()/AGAINST() functions and FULLTEXT index feature, this is probably what you are looking for.  Make sure a FULLTEXT index will operate reasonably on a json document.

What kind of data sizes are we talking about?  Huge amounts of memory is cheap these days, so having the entire Mysql dataset buffered in memory where you can do full text scans isn't unreasonable.

Breaking out some of the json field values and putting them into their own columns would allow you to search quickly for those ... but that doesn't help you for the general case.

Comment: Thanks, I don't need to search for the json values, only tags. How would I buffer the dataset into memory? The index won't be operating on the json itself, but on the tags field, if a fulltext index would speed things up Ill implement that.

Comment: ok, I see, the json wont be part of the search.  So fulltext should definitely work.  By buffering I mean what Mysql does automatically: it uses the server's ram to cache everything (tell Mysql how much ram it can use in my.cnf), so your queries are fast.

Answer (score 0):

This option you suggested is the correct design:

> One Idea I had was to put the tags into their own 2 column table (pid,
>   tag (key)). pid points to tid in the store table.

But if you're searching LIKE '%something%' then the leading '%' will mean the index can only be used to reduce disk reads - you will still need to scan the entire index.
If you can drop the leading % (because you now have the entire tags) then this is certainly the way to go.  The trailing '%' is not as important.